# Automated checking of Javascript and broken links

Tags: javascript, html, testing, automated-tests

I have a small home page which contains some javascript. It loads json and javascript libraries from other hosts, and generates links from this data.

I would like to check both for broken links toward other websites, and also check that my javascript works properly (e.g. no failure when loading distant json).

Is there any program I could run as a cron task to test that for me daily ?

Comment: Perform Ajax calls on each link and check http response object for errors like 404

Comment: And maintain somewhere in a file a list of all ajax requests that are performed in my web pages ? Looks wasteful. There must exist somewhere a code that executes the remote js (warns in case of error) and then checks the links.